# A contradiction between two definitions of cartesian product of two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

While studying elementary set theory, I got a unique definition of cartesian product of two sets from [here](http://users.metu.edu.tr/burakk/lecturenotes/320lecturenotes.pdf). It says - let $\mathit{A}$ and $\mathit{B}$ be sets. The cartesian product of $\mathit{A}$ and $\mathit{B}$ is the set $\{(\mathit{a,b}) \in \mathcal{P(P}\mathit{(A \cup B)) :a\in A ∧ b \in B}\}$ and is denoted by $\mathit{A\times B}$. Here $\mathcal{P}(\mathit{A \cup B})$ is the power set of $\mathit{A \cup B}$.

Now let us consider set

$ \mathit{A}=\{1\} \\ \mathit{B}=\{1,2\} \\ \text{then we have, } 
\mathit{A \cup B}=\{1,2\}\\ \text{then, } \mathcal{P}(\mathit{A \cup B})=\{\{1\},\{2\}, \{1,2\}, \phi \} \\ \text{hence, } \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\mathit{A \cup B} )) = \{\{\{1\}\},\{\{2\}\}, \{\{1,2\}\},\{\{1\}, \{2\}\},\{\{1\}, \{1,2\}\},\{\{2\}, \{1,2\}\},\{\{1\}, \{\phi\}\},\{\{2\}, \{\phi\}\},\{\{1,2\}, \{\phi\}\},\{\{1\},\{2\}, \{\phi\}\},\{\{1\},\{1,2\}, \{\phi\}\},\{\{2\},\{1,2\}, \{\phi\}\},\{\{1\},\{2\}, \{1,2\}\},\{\{1\},\{2\}, \{1,2\}, \{\phi\}\},\{\phi\}, \phi \}$

The common definition of the cartesian product of two sets $\mathit{A}$ and $\mathit{B}$ as we know is the set of all ordered pairs $(a,b)$, symbolically
$$
 A \times B = \{(a,b) :a\in A ∧ b \in B\}.
$$

From the common definition of the cartesian product of two sets ($\mathit{A}$ and $\mathit{B}$ ) we have

$\mathit{A \times B} = \{(1,1), (1,2)\} \text{, which } \notin \mathcal{P(P}\mathit{(A \cup B)) :a\in A ∧ b \in B}$.

Also, $\{(1,2)\}\in \mathit{A \times B}$ but that is different from $\{\{1,2\}\}\in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\mathit{A \cup B}))$. So here is a contradiction.

$\square$ **Question :** If This expression $\{(\mathit{a,b}) \in \mathcal{P(P}\mathit{(A \cup B)) :a\in A ∧ b \in B}\}$ is similar to $\mathit{A\times B}$, then why does a contradiction exist there? If I am wrong somewhere, would anyone kindly explain the correct way to think about this problem.

Any explanation is valuable and highly appreciated.

Comment: There are a great many things weird with the number of curly braces and parentheses going on here making it difficult to read the question correctly to try to see what you do or don't understand correctly.  $(1,2)\in A\times B$ but $\{(1,2)\}$ is not, rather $\{(1,2)\}\in \mathcal{P}(A\times B)$.  Now... it could be that the underlying issue is how one chooses to define $(a,b)$ rigorously in the first place.  After all, when talking from the perspective of first principles, parentheses are meaningless in this context.  One can define $(a,b)$ as $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$ and that might be whats up.

Comment: $\phi$ is a Greek letter. $\emptyset$, or $\varnothing$, is derived from the Nordic letter Ø.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Defining the ordered pair using set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Defining_the_ordered_pair_using_set_theory).

According to the most popular definition, we have that:

> $(1,2) =  \{  \{ 1 \}, \ \{ 1, \ 2 \} \}$.

As per your post, $A \cup B = \{ 1,2 \}$.

Thus, $\{ 1 \},  \{ 1, \ 2 \} \in \mathcal P (A \cup B)$ and so $(1,2) \in \mathcal P (\mathcal P (A \cup B))$.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer. For the product of three sets (for example) if I get a product like $(1,2,3) $ , then can we write it as $ \{  \{ 1 \}, \ \{ 1, \ 2 \}, \ \{ 1, \ 2, \ 3 \} \}$.

Comment: @TopoSet32 - not exactly; see [Tuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple). A possibility is using nested pairs: $(1,2,3)=((1,2),3)$